# how to get database to be attached in a listbox as a listform not a tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to attach the listbox with database but in rest i get the data in the form of tuple but i want to get it in the form of list

```
row=[]
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

# load the listbox with data
for item in rows:
     my_list.insert(END, item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

For Mysql.

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
root=Tk()
my_list=Listbox(root,bg="white")
my_list.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

conn=pymysql.connect(host="your_host",user="your_user",password="your_password",database="your_db")
cur=conn.cursor()
#=== Get all values from the table
cur.execute("select * from your_table")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print(rows)
# load the listbox with data
for item in rows:
   
   my_list.insert(END, str(item).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'","")) 

   
root.mainloop()
```

For sqlite3:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
root=Tk()
my_list=Listbox(root,bg="white")
my_list.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

conn = sql.connect("your_db.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

rows = cursor.execute("""select * from your_table""").fetchall()
# load the listbox with data
for item in rows:
   #for item1 in item:
   my_list.insert(END, str(item).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'",""))

   
root.mainloop()
```

You can also replace the the code where you add the data to list box with this, if you want the data in each cell on a separate line.

```
for item in rows:
   for item1 in item:
      my_list.insert(END, item1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map(str, item)` to convert items in the tuple to string, then use `.join()` to merge the tuple of strings into one string with specified separator:

```
for item in rows:
    my_list.insert(END, ", ".join(map(str, item)))
```